# MySQL:- Fetch records from 31 to 60 days

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a field called `date_created` with `TIMESTAMP` format now I have a requirement to fetch records between `0-30`,`31-60`,`61-90` like this.
I able to fetch record between months like

```
SELECT  received_quantity , delivery_qty , unit_cost
FROM    tbl_inward_list
WHERE   date_created BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
```

also

```
SELECT  received_quantity , delivery_qty , unit_cost
FROM    tbl_inward_list
WHERE   date_created BETWEEN DATE_SUB( CURDATE( ) ,INTERVAL 2 MONTH ) AND DATE_SUB( CURDATE() ,INTERVAL 1 MONTH )
```

But I want a query between `31 to 60` also `61 to 90` like this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT  received_quantity , delivery_qty , unit_cost
FROM    tbl_inward_list
WHERE   datediff(current_date,date(date_created)) BETWEEN  31 AND 60;
```

Similarly

```
SELECT  received_quantity , delivery_qty , unit_cost
FROM    tbl_inward_list
WHERE   datediff(current_date,date(date_created)) BETWEEN  61 AND 90;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WHERE   date_created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY
  AND   date_created  < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY

WHERE   date_created >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY
  AND   date_created  < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 60 DAY
```

No, don't use 31 and 61; use the inequality.

`CURDATE()` will give you boundaries at midnight; `NOW()` will be based on the current time.  (This matters if `date_created` is a `DATETIME` instead of a `DATE`.)

Don't use `DATEDIFF`, it would let you use any index involving `date_created` for efficiency.